# "Как только не/ни перекрутишь факты..." — частица не или ни?

Tags: орфография, не-или-ни

Подскажите пожалуйста правильное написание предложения:
"Как только **ни** перекрутишь <факты>, лишь бы доказать <свою> правоту" или "Как только **не** перекрутишь <факты>, лишь бы доказать <свою> правоту"

Answer (score 6):

Я попробую дополнить Людмилу. У Розенталя и в других источниках этот момент обычно отдельно не обговаривается (как самоочевидный, что ли?), но ***НЕ*** здесь действительно отрицательная частица.

Оперировать только надо не положениями из начала подпункта, а следующими за ними:

> 5. В независимых восклицательных и вопросительных предложениях (часто со словами только, уж) пишется отрицательная частица не, а в придаточных предложениях (с уступительным оттенком значения) для усиления утвердительного смысла – частица ни. Ср.: *Куда только он не обращался! (общий смысл: «обращался во многие места»). – Куда только он ни обращался, везде встречал равнодушное отношение; Что мать не делала для больного сына! – Чего мать ни делала для больного сына, как ни пыталась помочь ему, но спасти его не смогла*. Ср. также: ***На какие только ухищрения не пускается маленький человек, чтобы не пропасть, добыть горсточку счастья, какие только профессии себе не придумывает, а удачи все нет и нет*** (при помощи союза а соединены независимые предложения, в первой части нет придаточного предложения с уступительным оттенком значения, поэтому пишется не). ***Чего только не дают, а он ни в какую*** (аналогичный случай).

В нашем случае, думаю, речь не идет о придаточном, да и необходимого уступительного значения тут нет.

Сравните:

От Москвы до Бреста
Нет такого места,
Где бы ***не скитались*** мы в пыли

(Симонов)

"Не" здесь означает, что такого места НЕТ, скитались везде. 
В разбираемых же случаях первая часть этого отрицания просто опущена.

как только не перекрутишь <факты>, лишь бы доказать <свою> правоту

[Нет места,] где только не приходилось ему бывать!
[Нет (способа),] как только не перекрутишь <факты>, лишь бы доказать <свою> правоту.

Comment: От Москвы до Бреста
Нет такого места,
Где бы не скитались мы в пыли
Здесь разница с примером принципиальная - двойное отрицание. Нет места, где бы мы не скитались. Наш случай на основании этого рассматривать нельзя

Comment: >Здесь разница с примером принципиальная - двойное отрицание  
  
Мне сдается, что Вы или невнимательно прочитали или не очень поняли.
Речь именно о том, что случаи аналогичны, второе отрицание просто опущено. Если у вас возражения по моей **логике**, я Вас внимательно слушаю. А просто выдавать банальность за аргумент - это не ко мне.

Comment: Я прочитал очень внимательно, и второго подразумеваемого отрицания в своем примере я просто не вижу

Comment: Действительно, Бегемот очень не внимателен.

Answer (score 4):

Поддерживаю Екатерину, частица НЕ - отрицательная, частица ТОЛЬКО усиливает отрицание, это её роль. Усилительной НИ была бы частица в придаточном уступительном, но данное предложение не придаточное уступительное: "Как только ни перекрутишь <факты>- главное, т.е. независимое предложение(зачем? с какой целью?), лишь бы(чтобы) доказать <свою> правоту".-придаточное цели.

Следовательно, это независимое предложение, частица отрицательная - НЕ.

Comment: Вот у Розенталя объясняется: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/38.htm   : На какие только ухищрения не пускается маленький человек, чтобы не пропасть, добыть горсточку счастья, какие только профессии себе не придумывает, а удачи все нет и нет (при помощи союза а соединены независимые предложения, в первой части нет придаточного предложения с уступительным оттенком значения, поэтому пишется не). Чего только не дают, а он ни в какую (аналогичный случай).

Comment: Такие предложения по форме отрицательные, и частица используется отрицательная: Где только не приходилось ему бывать! Куда он только не обращался!
А по содержанию всегда содержат утверждение. (Кто не знал этого человека! означает 'все знали этого человека'; Где только не приходилось ему бывать! означает 'ему всюду приходилось бывать'.В Вашем предложении смысл такой же.

Comment: Чего только не дают, а он ни в какую (аналогичный случай).
На основании этого примера тоже нельзя делать выводы, поскольку он соответствует абсолютно другому правилу

Comment: Какому же? Принципиально здесь как раз, самостоятельное или зависимое предложение, а восклицательное или нет-бывает авторская интонация, а смысл остаётся тот же: Как только не перекрутишь факты! Как только не перекрутишь факты, чтобы доказать свою правоту! Как только не перекрутишь факты, лишь бы доказать свою правоту. - смысл один, а интонация меняется, потому что после него стоит ещё одно предложение, которое и снижает тон. А частица НИ усиливает отрицание в предложениях типа НИкто НЕ был,НИкогда НЕ пойду.

Comment: Сравните предложение в вопросе (где нужно писать "не") со следующим:
**Как ни перекручивай факты, а правоту свою не докажешь.**

Тогда, возможно, будет проще вычленить грамматическую разницу между "не" и "ни".

Answer (score 3):

Только НЕ! КАК ТОЛЬКО НЕ ПЕРЕКРУТИШЬ! После КАК стоит частица ТОЛЬКО, которая влияет на выбор НЕ. 
В независимых восклицательных и вопросительных предложениях (при наличии или возможности подстановки усилительных ***частиц только, уж***) пишется отрицательная частица **не**: ***Куда он только не обращался!*** (частица только усиливает последующее отрицание). [Здесь](http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.58)

Comment: Аналогично - с приведенным вами примером Куда он только нИ обращался!

Answer (score 0):

Надо писать с ни, т.к.нет отрицания. Задайте вопрос: перекрутишь факты? Ответ: да, перекрутишь,значит, нам нужна не отрицательная частица не, а усилительная ни.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос настолько интересный и непростой, что не могу пройти мимо.

Здесь требуется НЕ, но я бы слегка подредактировал это предложение:

**Как только не перекрутишь факты, чтобы доказать свою правоту.**

Я вижу здесь риторический вопрос: а есть ли такой способ "перекручивания", к которому ты **не** прибегнешь, чтобы доказать свою правоту? С этой точки зрения роль отрицательной частицы *не* становится, по-моему, более очевидной.