# Частицы "не" и "ни": как различить?

Tags: не-или-ни

Подскажите, пожалуйста,частица "не" или "ни" должна стоять в следующем предложении?

*Кому они только ни (не) приписывают победу* (далее следует перечисление).

Answer (score 2):

Здесь правильным вариантом является отрицательная частица **не**.

То есть *нет* того из перечисленных, кому победа *не* приписывалась бы (двойное отрицание порождает утверждение).

По суровому правилу **не** ставится в восклицательном предложении (коего не наблюдается), а у нас говорящий - малоэмоциональный меланхолик, ему простительна повествовательная интонация.

Ну и усилительная частица **только** играет положенную ей роль: помогает отрицать.

[ПРАВОПИСАНИЕ ЧАСТИЦ НЕ и НИ](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.58)

> Одноименные частицы **не** и **ни** различаются по значению: **не** —
>   отрицательная, **ни** — усилительная. Поэтому в придаточных
>   уступительных частях предложений для усиления утвердительного смысла
>   употребляется частица **ни**: *И во всю ночь безумец бедный, куда
>   стопы ни обращал, за ним повсюду Всадник Медный с тяжелым топотом
>   скакал* (П.), а в независимых восклицательных и вопросительных
>   предложениях ***(при наличии или возможности подстановки усилительных
>   частиц только, уж)*** пишется отрицательная частица **не**: *Куда он
>   только не обращался!* (частица только усиливает последующее
>   отрицание).

---

[Вот у Розенталя объясняется: **evartist.narod.ru/text1/38.htm**: *На какие только ухищрения не пускается маленький человек, чтобы не пропасть, добыть горсточку счастья, какие только профессии себе не придумывает, а удачи все нет и нет* (при помощи союза а соединены независимые предложения, в первой части нет придаточного предложения с уступительным оттенком значения, поэтому пишется **не**).](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/23493/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B8)

Answer (score 2):

***Кому они только не приписывают победу.***

1) Обычно это риторический вопрос с таким содержанием: **Кому** они не приписывают победу? **Всем** приписывают.

2) Простые восклицательные предложения с частицей НЕ являются риторическими (то есть не требующими ответа ввиду его ясности), при этом заключённое в них **отрицание** фактически имеет значение **скрытого утверждения.** Именно поэтому часто возникают вопросы **при выборе частиц НЕ или НИ.**

Дело в том, что **обобщение,** которое содержит риторический вопрос с **грамматическим отрицанием** и частицей НЕ, обычно свойственно **уступительным** предложениям с частицей НИ

*Наш брат охотник куда не заходит!  Кто только не бывал у Горького!  Как не любить родной Москвы! Ну как не порадеть родному человечку!*

3) Возможный парный вариант с частицей НИ: ***Кому бы они ни приписывали победу***, сейчас это было уже не важно. Это  СПП с придаточным уступительным.

4) Конечно, мы исходим из того, что НИ – усилительная частица, а НЕ – отрицательная частица. Но имея только эту информацию, трудно быстро решать такие задачи.

**Поэтому на помощь приходит грамматика.** Нужно обязательно определить вид предложения: простое или сложное, придаточное уступительное или определительное.

5) Вот еще **парные примеры**, которые решаются с **помощью грамматики без длинных рассуждений об усилении и отрицании:**

***Куда ни*** наступишь, **везде** вода (уступительное придаточное, обобщение).

*Это был край, **куда не** ступала нога человека* (определительное придаточное, край какой?).

***Куда я только не обращался***! (Риторический вопрос, простое восклицательное предложение).

***Куда я ни обращался***, ответ был один и тот же (уступительное придаточное).

Answer (score 0):

Здесь правильным вариантом является усилительная частица **ни**. Это объясняется значением сочетания, обозначающим явление, при котором происходило поочерёдное приписывание победы определённым лицам, причём акцент делается на том, что их может быть любое количество. Если говорить проще, то данная частица служит для постановки логического удаления на то, что победа по ошибке приписывалась то одним, то другим людям. В таком случае эту частицу, как и любую другую усилительную, можно изъять из предложения, при этом смысл не изменится **кардинально**. То есть может существовать предложение, эквивалентное данному:

**Кому они только (пропуск „ни”) приписывали победу**.

Соглашусь, что данное предложение всё же режет уши, но я и не говорю, что оно уместно. По сути при выборе частицы мы просто представляем себе подобную конструкцию, проверяя изменение смысла.

Теперь, чтобы окончательно усвоить данную тему, скажу, что при попытке „выброса” частицы **не** происходит так называемая инвертация (смена в противоположную сторону. Простите за термин из информатики) значения. Приведу пример:

**Мальчик не читает книгу**.

**Мальчик (пропуск „не”) читает книгу**.

Как видите, произошла кардинальная смена значения. Конечно, далеко не самый лучший пример, но, надеюсь, суть понятна. Если возникли вопросы, то оставьте комментарий к данному ответу.

Comment: Вот поэтому я и спросил,слишком уж режет слух:)

Comment: Но ведь орфографические правила говорят, что нужно писать _не_...

Comment: Я бы сказал, что здесь можно написать и **не**, и **ни**. Для окончательного решения необходим контекст. Мои рассуждения были насчёт того случая, при котором предложение является повествовательным.

Comment: Появились ответы,доказывающие,что в вышеозначенном предложении правильно будет написать частицу"не".А как быть с дальнейшим перечислением?То есть в предложении было двоеточие,а после этого шло перечисление тех,кому эту победу приписывают.

Comment: @ПётрГринёв Воспользуйтесь возможностью редактировать свой вопрос и напишите предложение полностью. Двоеточие и повествовательная интонация нисколько не мешают употреблению частицы "не".